# Anti-debug clearing hardware breakpoints

Tags: windows, anti-debugging, breakpoint

An application I am debugging somehow manages to clear my hardware breakpoints. I am using TitanHide and x64dbg.

I am observing the following behaviour:

- When placing the first hw breakpoint, it is hit only once - still appears visible in x64dbg but I guess it is disabled in reality and x64dbg doesn't know that.
- When placing another breakpoint, the **first** breakpoint is hit exactly once.

I am not sure what causes this obscure behaviour, but what I do know is that my hardware breakpoints are not getting hit, so I researched what could possibly clear them. I have come up with:

- ZwSetInformationThread to hide the thread from the debugger.
- SetThreadContext to reset the debug registers .
- Installing a vectored exception handler, cause an exception deliberately, and modify the context from there

However all 3 methods should be caught by TitanHide, and exceptions should show up in the log of x64dbg (which they don't). Are there any further methods to clear hardware breakpoints?

Comment: Are you sure that the instruction on which you set the HW breakpoint is actually being executed?
The program may detect a HW breakpoint (using GetThreadContext and reading debug registers). The program may then behave differently.

Comment: @Yotamz possible, I'll check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a mixture of hardware breakpoint related bugs in x64dbg (which are fixed by now), and a driver denying access to **some** threads of the target application (meaning the hardware breakpoint could not be set on those). If you encounter this, I suggest updating and checking OpenThread permissions, as x64dbg fails silently here :/